# julia dataframe changing one cell changes entire row

Tags: dataframe, julia

Consider the following code, where I want to change only 1 cell, but the entire row gets changed:

```
df=DataFrames.DataFrame(A=[1,2],B=[3,4])

df[2,:A]=7 # this is OK, changes only 1 cell

df[:,1:end]=0.0 # this line somehow makes the change in the next line behave unexpectedly

df[2,:A]=7 # entire 2nd row is 7
```

It's as if the `df[:,1:end]=0.0` sets all the cells of that row to the same reference; but I am setting it to 0.0, so I expect this to be a value copy, not reference copy

Versions: 
julia version 0.4.6-pre
DataFrames v"0.7.8"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's some aliasing going on here. I think this is a bug in `DataFrames`, though it's possible that it's intended behaviour, albeit strange. What's happening is that the same underlying data is being used by both columns. See [#1052](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFrames.jl/pull/1052).

As a workaround, you can set the columns one by one:

```
for c in 1:size(df, 2)
    df[:,c] = 0.0
end
```

Comment: It might be intended; it seems like it's slicing to me. If you do `df[:,:]` or `df[1:end,1:end]` instead, it works as intended. My guess is `df[:,1:end]` unintentionally changes the underlying rank, and `= 0.` is interpreted as broadcasting somehow

Comment: Maybe there's a "fill" command used under the hood to implement broadcasting, causing the aliasing?

Comment: Hi Tasos, there's some discussion on the issue in [#1052](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFrames.jl/pull/1052).